# running a gulp build in kudu on local iis

Tags: node.js, git, gulp, kudu

I'm running some tests on a local version of Kudu and trying to understand how to run a gulp build process before kudu syncs the outputted build to the wwwroot folder.

My web project is structured like so:

```
-bower_components/
-node_modules/
-source/
.bowerrc
.gitignore
bower.json
gulpfile.js
package.json
```

Running gulp generates the build in a build folder at the project root.
The reason for this set up is to ensure any git node or pre-complied source files are not exposed on the web when a deployment or ftp upload is run.

I cannot figure out how to get kudu to run a gulp build task first and to then take sync the contents of that build output to wwwroot

I get the following npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.1
3 info using node@v4.4.4
4 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'
4 verbose stack     at Error (native)
5 verbose cwd C:\kudu\apps\devsite\site\wwwroot
6 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
7 error argv "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
8 error node v4.4.4
9 error npm  v2.15.1
10 error path C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm
11 error code EPERM
12 error errno -4048
13 error syscall mkdir
14 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'
14 error     at Error (native)
14 error  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm']
14 error   errno: -4048,
14 error   code: 'EPERM',
14 error   syscall: 'mkdir',
14 error   path: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm' }
15 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
16 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

And from the deployment log

```
Updating branch 'master'.,cffcb371-6058-4ec3-aa69-a979ef8976a4,0
Updating submodules.,500605d6-55df-418c-bae1-1eb6ec24ec10,0
Preparing deployment for commit id '872c8ef074'.,936863bc-e83f-49ed-950a-cfb67aaaf10f,0
Generating deployment script.,2e77d73d-517a-47e6-b7da-b46ee6b0a34f,0
Using the following command to generate deployment script: 'azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment -r "C:\kudu\apps\devsite\site\repository" -o "C:\kudu\apps\devsite\site\deployments\tools" --node --sitePath "C:\kudu\apps\devsite\site\repository"'.,,0
Generating deployment script for node.js Web Site,,0
Generated deployment script files,,0
Running deployment command...,f5250b3f-afeb-455e-bc2e-68f01a7200a0,0
Command: "C:\kudu\apps\devsite\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd",,0
Handling node.js deployment.,,0
KuduSync.NET from: 'C:\kudu\apps\devsite\site\repository' to: 'C:\kudu\apps\devsite\site\wwwroot',,0
Deleting file: 'hostingstart.html',,0
Copying file: '.bowerrc',,0
Copying file: '.gitignore',,0
Copying file: 'bower.json',,0
Copying file: 'gulpfile.js',,0
Copying file: 'package.json',,0
Copying file: 'README.md',,0
Copying file: 'source\.htaccess',,0
Copying file: 'source\.htpasswd',,0
Copying file: 'source\hero-banners.html',,0
Copying file: 'source\index.html',,0
Omitting next output lines...,,0
Invalid start-up command "npm install && bower install" in package.json. Please use the format "node <script relative path>".,,1
Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.,,0
Missing server.js/app.js files&comma; web.config is not generated,,1
The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.,,0
The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 4.4.4.,,0
One or more of the selected node/npm paths do not exist.,,0
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted&comma; mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm',,1
at Error (native),,1
,,1
Finished successfully.,,0
Deployment successful.,30b733dd-4038-4dbb-b103-b7852c2586c1,0
```

I assume some of the errors are permission errors which I believe can correct in iis.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the EPERM issue.
In IIS application pool identities need to be set to local system